# I can't store all values from user inputs in the array. On window alert only the first array value shows up

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post, clone

I can't seem to save all the clone inputs into an array and pass the array via $.post(). For some reason it only passes the first array value that user selects.

I would like to

1. pass array by $.Post()
2. receive true or false if all items in array don't exist in mysql via a php.

I am stuck on the array only holding the value of the original input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("p:last").after($("p:first").clone(true)
                                  .find("#Equi").val("").end()
    );
  });
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ar1 = [];
  var input = document.getElementById('#Equi');
  $('#Equi').on('change', function() {
    // $.post('UnitValidate2.php', {Unit: ar1}, function(data) {
    ar1.push(input.value);
    window.alert(ar1);
    $.post('UnitValidate2.php', {Unit: ar1}, function(data) {
      window.alert(data);
      if(data == "True") {
        window.alert("Move On");
      } else {
        window.alert("Cant call out unit");
        // $("#Equi").val("");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<!--for clone   -->
<p>
  <label for="lname">Eqiupment:</label>
  <!--<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">-->
  <input type="text" name="Unit[]" id="Equi" value="" list="namelist4" required/>
  <datalist id="namelist4">
  <select name="Nam" style="display:none">
  <?php
    // Include config file
    require_once "../Login/config.php";
    $conn1 = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM `Status` WHERE Active = 'Yes' AND Status = 'Ready For Rent' ORDER BY Unit ASC";
    result4 = mysqli_query($conn1,$sql4);
    while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row4['Unit']."'>".$row4['Unit']."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</option>
</select>
</datalist>
```

Comment: is this php?
are you using jquery?

Comment: i am using jquery. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help us to help you - please format your code properly (indentation).It makes it so much easier to read - and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still a lot unclear to me. I left out the PHP part where you fill the options in the `<select>` element. I also made up some elements for your `<datalist>` element. And ...

Since you *are* using jQuery you might as well use it *properly*: I changed your data collecting part to

```
var ar1=$('.Equi').get().map(el=>el.value);
```

where I search for all elements of class=`Equi` (I had to change this from `id` to `class`, since Ids must always be *unique*!), then extract them as a JavaScript Array (`.get()`), use `.map()` to get their `.value` attribute and eventually return the resulting array into `ar1`.

Since this snippet runs on Stackoverflow I had to comment out the actual `$.post()` commands but the `console.log()` shows what would have been posted in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {     
    $("p:last").after($("p:first").clone(true).find(".Equi").val("").end() );
  });
  
  $('.Equi').on('change', function(){  
       var ar1=$('.Equi').get().map(el=>el.value);
       console.log("this will be posted:",ar1);
       if (false) $.post('UnitValidate2.php',{Unit: ar1}, function(data){
         console.log(data);
         if(data == "True"){ console.log("Move On ");}
         else {              console.log("Cant call out unit");}
       });   

   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add</button><br>
<datalist id="namelist4">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</datalist>
<p>
  <label for="lname">Eqiupment
  <input type="text" name="Unit[]" class="Equi" value="" list="namelist4" required/>:</label>
  <select name="Nam">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. i spend 4 long days trying to get it to make sense and work.